# How do I create a basic UIButton programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, programmatically-created

How can I create a basic `UIButton` programmatically? For example in my view controller, when executing the `viewDidLoad` method, three `UIButton`s will be created dynamically and its layout or properties are set.

Comment: http://webindream.com/how-to-add-uibutton-programmatically-in-swift/ has a good tutorial to add uibutton programmatically

Comment: Create UIButton in Swift, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102191/make-a-uibutton-programmatically-in-swift/54146279#54146279

Answer (score 1213, accepted):

Here's one:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: Thanks! can you explain to me what is aMethod?

Comment: aMethod is your own defined method which will respond to the button press. (For me)It takes an id object.

Comment: When the button is manipulated (pressed and held down, or pressed and released or dragged through, etc) you want something to happen, right?  The code that you want called is usually a method like:

- (void) myButtonWasPressed or 

- (void) myButtonWasPressed:(id) whichButton

That's what I am talking about.

Comment: The aMethod is kinda like and IBaction that is called when the button is tapped.

Comment: You don't need [UIButton alloc] to reserve memory? Or does buttonWithType: handle this?

Comment: buttonWithType: returns an autoreleased instance of UIButton

Comment: Handy Tip: If you don't want your button to activate as soon as you touch it, use UIControlEventTouchUpInside instead of UIControlEventTouchDown - this will wait for the user to lift their finger, giving them the option of cancelling by dragging away (recommended in Apple Human Interface Guidelines)

Comment: buttonWithType is cerated as autoreleased, but then when -addSubview is called, the button is retained until it is removed from the view.

Comment: I do recommend using UIControlEventTouchUpInside for most cases.  I have used UIControlEventTouchDown in some games and music playing apps  (ClefTunes and ClefNotes) so that the touch immediately generates music notes.

Comment: Note for the people like me that struggled with this--@selector(aMethod:) refers to a method with an argument. @selector(aMethod) refers to a method with no argument. If your method signature looks like -(void) aMethod; and you use @selector(aMethod:), your app will crash.

Comment: On iOS 7.0 you may want to customize the button more. I have a [iOS 7.0 UIButton code and animations](http://iphonedev.tv/blog/2014/1/22/programmatic-uibutton-on-ios-70-create-a-uibutton-with-code) to show UIButton variations.

Comment: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect is deprecated. It is equal to UIButtonTypeSystem

Answer (score 101):

**Objective-C**

```
UIButton *but= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[but addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [but setFrame:CGRectMake(52, 252, 215, 40)];
[but setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[but setExclusiveTouch:YES];

 // if you like to add backgroundImage else no need
   [but setbackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"XXX.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.view addSubview:but];

-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
 {
NSLog(@"you clicked on button %@", sender.tag);
 }
```

**Swift**

```
    let myButton = UIButton() // if you want to set the type use like UIButton(type: .RoundedRect) or UIButton(type: .Custom)
    myButton.setTitle("Hai Touch Me", forState: .Normal)
    myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: .Normal)
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(15, 50, 300, 500)
    myButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressedAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview( myButton)


func pressedAction(sender: UIButton!) {
   // do your stuff here 
  NSLog("you clicked on button %@", sender.tag)
}
```

**Swift3 and above**

```
  let myButton = UIButton() // if you want to set the type use like UIButton(type: .RoundedRect) or UIButton(type: .Custom)
    myButton.setTitle("Hi, Click me", for: .normal)
    myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
    myButton.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 50, width: 300, height: 500)

    myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressedAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview( myButton)



func pressedAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
   // do your stuff here 
  print("you clicked on button \(sender.tag)")
}
```

**SwiftUI**

for example you get the step by step implemntation from [SwiftUI Developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/working-with-ui-controls)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            Text("Target Color Black")
             Button(action: { 
                 /* handle button action here */ })
            {
         Text("your Button Name")
          .color(.white)
                        .padding(10)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                        .shadow(radius: 5)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
     }


        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: swift 3: gives error `exped declaration` at myButton.setTitle("Hi, Click")

Comment: @XcodianSolangi -- is not `myButton.setTitle("Hi, Click")` the syntax is `myButton.setTitle("Hi, Click me", for: .normal)` i tried my code i am not faced any issues

Comment: i write as it as you defined, now i have defined constant in VC and other parts inside the function

Answer (score 96):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self addMyButton];   // Call add button method on view load
}

- (void)addMyButton{    // Method for creating button, with background image and other properties

    UIButton *playButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
    playButton.frame = CGRectMake(110.0, 360.0, 100.0, 30.0);
    [playButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    playButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [playButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blueButton.png"];
    UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteButton.png"];
    UIImage *strechableButtonImagePressed = [buttonImagePressed stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:playButton];  
}
```

Comment: @ sasayins: I have arranged the code, you can call addMyButton method on viewDidLoad.

Comment: thanks... but why use viewController:viewDidLoad? it seems like this stuff (setting up of the view/adding buttons) should be done in the view instead of the view controller? thanks

Comment: @rakkarage The addMyButton() method is generic method, you can use it from event.

Comment: A much better answer than the one accepted, because it shows context for the code.

Comment: It seems it is not a good idea (??) to do initialization of coordinates of view in viewDidLoad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882199/view-height-problems-continued ???

Answer (score 32):

To add a button programatically to your controller's view, use the following:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
   [btn setTitle:@"Hello, world!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [self.view addSubview:btn];
}
```

To add three of these, rinse and repeat.

Comment: It seems it is not a good idea (??) to do initialization of coordinates of view in viewDidLoad: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882199/view-height-problems-continued ???

Comment: Correct, there are better approaches now than there were in 2009.

Answer (score 27):

Here you can create dynamically a UIButton:

```
//For button image
UIImage *closebtnimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"close_btn.png"];
//Custom type button
btnclose = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]retain];
//Set frame of button means position
btnclose.frame = CGRectMake(103, 257, 94, 32);
//Button with 0 border so it's shape like image shape
[btnclose.layer setBorderWidth:0];
//Set title of button
[btnclose setTitle:@"CLOSE" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnclose addTarget:self action:@selector(methodname:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//Font size of title
btnclose.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
//Set image of button
[btnclose setBackgroundImage:closebtnimg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 26):

Come on, it's ***2014!*** Why isn't **code block evaluation assignment** being used yet, as [trends show](http://nshipster.com/new-years-2014/) it's the **future!**

```
UIButton* button = ({
    //initialize button with frame
    UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:({
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 200.0, 75.0);
        frame;
    })];
    //set button background color
    [button setBackgroundColor:({
        UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
        color;
    })];
    //set button title for state
    [button setTitle:({
        NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"title words"];
        string;
    }) forState:({
        UIControlState state = UIControlStateNormal;
        state;
    })];
    //set selector
    [button addTarget:self action:({
        SEL select = @selector(method:);
        select;
    }) forControlEvents:({
        UIControlEvents event = UIControlEventTouchUpInside;
        event;
    })];
    //return button
    button;
});
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

[image: whoa!]

whoa!

Or the exact results can be accomplished as such:

```
UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 200.0, 75.0)];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0]];
[button setTitle:@"title words" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(method:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

---

Comment: A little over the top, but it's an interesting new feature.

Comment: That's the point, to show off code block evaluation and ANSWER the question. It's annoying this is getting -1's...

Comment: you will have more upvotes if you give explanation for ***why code block evaluation assignment*** *is important...*

Comment: @FahimParkar, the question is how to make a button not how and why CBE is important.

Comment: I comment with context to ***Come on, it's 2014!***

Answer (score 20):

`'action:@selector(aMethod:)'` write method like this :

```
- (void)aMethod:(UIButton*)button
   {
         NSLog(@"Button  clicked.");
  }
```

It works for me. Thanks. KS.

Answer (score 15):

**Objective-C**

```
// Create the Button with RoundedRect type
UIButton *mybutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
// instend of "Click Me" you can write your own message/Label
[mybutton setTitle:@"Click Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// create the Rectangle Frame with specified size
mybutton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 140); // x,y,width,height    [self.view addSubview:mybutton];// add button to your view.
```

**Swift**

```
let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
button.setTitle("Test Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 10):

try this code to create a button and repeat it for 2 more times with different coordinates and the method(myButtonClick) is called when the button is pressed

```
UIButton *editButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
editButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
[editButton setBackgroundImage: editButtonImage forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClick:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
editButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
editButton.titleLabel.text = @"Edit";
editButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
editButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
editButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica" size: 14];
[self.view addSubview: editButton];

-(void) myButtonClick:(NSString *)myString{

   NSLog(@"you clicked on button %@", myString);
}
```

Comment: What is myString set to?

Comment: that is the string to pass as a parameter
just for additional info, you can also use that method like this
-(void) myButtonClick{

   NSLog(@"you clicked on button");
}
but be sure that while calling the method remove the : just use like this
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClick)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: +1 for showing how to set multiple settings instead of just creating a button.

Answer (score 9):

Check out this code:

**Swift 4.2**

```
let frameimg = CGRect(x: 15, y: 46, width: 55, height: 70)
let btnTest = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
btnTest.frame = frameimg
btnTest.tag = 11
btnTest.setTitle("Test Button", for: .normal)
btnTest.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
btnTest.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
btnTest.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
btnTest.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
btnTest.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
btnTest.setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, for: .normal)
btnTest.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .selected)
btnTest.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
view.addSubview(btnTest)
```

**Objective C**

```
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(15, 46, 55,70);
UIButton  *SelectionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
SelectionButton.frame=frameimg;
SelectionButton.tag=i;
[SelectionButton setTitle:[SelectionArray objectAtIndex:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[SelectionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnSelected:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[SelectionButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0]];
SelectionButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
SelectionButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
SelectionButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[SelectionButton setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
[SelectionButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[SelectionButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
[self.view addSubview:SelectionButton];
```

I hope this code will work for you.

Answer (score 7):

You can just put the creator instance within a loop and dynamically add names from an array if you so wish.

Comment: yup i tried mahboudz, and at the same time, i tried the looping. thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 100.0, 300.0, 20.0);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
-(UIButton *)addButton:(NSString *)title :(CGRect)frame : (SEL)selector :(UIImage *)image :(int)tag{

UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = frame;
[btn addTarget:self action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
btn.tag = tag;

return btn;

}
```

and you can add it to the view:

```
[self.view addSubview:[self addButton:nil :self.view.frame :@selector(btnAction:) :[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] :1]];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
       action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an example as well to create three buttons. Just move their location.

```
UIImage *buttonOff = [UIImage imageNamed:@"crysBallNorm.png"];
UIImage *buttonOn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"crysBallHigh.png"];

UIButton *predictButton = [UIButton alloc];
predictButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
predictButton.frame = CGRectMake(180.0, 510.0, 120.0, 30.0);
[predictButton setBackgroundImage:buttonOff forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[predictButton setBackgroundImage:buttonOn forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[predictButton setTitle:@"Predict" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[predictButton setTitleColor:[UIColor purpleColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[predictButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:predictButton];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create button by this code.

```
 UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
 [btn setTitle:@"click button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  btn.frame = CGRectMake(50, 100, 80, 40);
  [self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Here is the button action method

```
 -(void)btnAction
 {
   NSLog(@"button clicked");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

For creating UIButton programmatically we can create in both objective c and swift

**SWIFT 3**

```
let buttonSwift   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system) as UIButton
                      //OR 
let buttonSwift   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
//Set Frame for Button
buttonSwift.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)
//Set title for button
buttonSwift.setTitle("ClickMe", for: .normal)
//If you want to set color for button title
buttonSwift.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
//If you want to set Background color for button
buttonSwift.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
//If you want to set tag for button
buttonSwift.tag = 0
//If you want to add or set image for button
let image = UIImage(named: "YourImageName") as UIImage?
buttonSwift.setImage(image, for: .normal)
//If you want to add or set Background image for button
buttonSwift.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
//Add action for button
buttonSwift.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionPressMe), for:.touchUpInside)
//Add button as SubView to Super View
self.view.addSubview(buttonSwift)
```

UIButton Action Method

```
func actionPressMe(sender: UIButton!) 
{
    NSLog("Clicked button tag is %@", sender.tag)
               OR
    print("Clicked button tag is \(sender.tag)")

    //Then do whatever you want to do here

    ........  
}
```

**OBJECTIVE C**

```
UIButton *buttonObjectiveC = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
           OR
UIButton *buttonObjectiveC = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
buttonObjectiveC.frame = CGRectMake(200, 100, 200, 100);
//Set title for button
[buttonObjectiveC setTitle:@"ClickMe" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//If you want to set color for button title
[buttonObjectiveC setTitleColor:[UIColor  whiteColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
//If you want to set Background color for button
[buttonObjectiveC setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
//If you want to set tag for button
buttonSwift.tag = 0;
//If you want to add or set image for button
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageName"];
[buttonObjectiveC setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//If you want to add or set Background image for button
[buttonObjectiveC setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//Add action for button
[buttonObjectiveC addTarget:self action:@selector(actionPressMe:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//Add button as SubView to Super View
[self.view addSubview:buttonObjectiveC];
```

UIButton Action Method

```
- (void)actionPressMe:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"Clicked button tag is %@",sender.tag);
    //Then do whatever you want to do here
    ..........
}
```

Output Screenshot is

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 2.0:

```
let btnObject : UIButton  = UIButton() 
btnObject.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: 89, width: 70, height: 22)

btnObject.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 13)
btnObject.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
btnObject.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 189/255, green: 176/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
btnObject.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
btnObject.addTarget(self, action: "btnbtnObjectClick:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
subView.addSubview(btnObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it....

```
UIButton *finalPriceBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
finalPriceBtn.frame=CGRectMake(260, 25, 45, 15);
[finalPriceBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(goBtnClk:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
finalPriceBtn.titleLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
[finalPriceBtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f",tempVal] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
finalPriceBtn.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 2.0f/255.0f green: 155.0f/255.0f blue: 213.0f/255.0f  alpha:1];
finalPriceBtn.titleLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
[imageView addSubview:finalPriceBtn];
```

Hope i helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)addStuffToView
{
    UIButton *aButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20)]; //(x, y, width, height of button on screen
    [aButton setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];//puts the text on the button
    aButton.titleLabel.font = somefont;//sets the font if one is already stated
    aButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-MT" size:12];//sets the font type and size
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];//see back method below
    [aButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//sets the image of the button
    [self.view addSubview:back];
}

-(void)back
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle.....]
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self addStuffToView];//adds all items built in this method to the view
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it in your `ViewDidLoad` Method:

```
continuebtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, view1.frame.size.width-20, 40)];
    [continuebtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [continuebtn setTitle:@"Continue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    continuebtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    continuebtn.layer.borderWidth =1.0;
    continuebtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    [continuebtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [continuebtn addTarget:self action:@selector(continuetonext) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [view1 addSubview:continuebtn];
```

Where `continuetonext` is:

```
-(void)continuetonext
{
    GeneratePasswordVC *u = [[GeneratePasswordVC alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:u animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 2.2 (with the with the new "selector" declaration).

```
let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20) // set any frame you want
btn.setTitle("MyAction", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyClass.myAction(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(btn)


func myAction(sender:UIButton!){
  // Some action 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Swift 3, several changes have been made to the syntax.

> Here is how you would go about creating a basic button as of Swift 3:

```
    let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    button.setTitle("Example Button", for: UIControlState.normal)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Here are the changes that have been made since previous versions of Swift:

```
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

// system no longer capitalised

button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)

// CGRectMake has been removed as of Swift 3

button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

// greenColor replaced with green

button.setTitle("Example Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

// normal is no longer capitalised

self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *custombutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[custombutton addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(aMethod:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[custombutton setTitle:@"Click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
custombutton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 110.0, 160.0, 40.0);
custombutton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 2.0f/255.0f green: 155.0f/255.0f blue: 213.0f/255.0f  alpha:1];
 [custombutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hh.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [view addSubview:custombutton];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *buttonName = [UIButton
buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[buttonName addTarget:self 
    action:@selector(aMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[buttonName setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0); [view
addSubview:buttonName];
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 3** (even shorter code)

```
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200.0, height: 40.0)
button.addTarget(nil, action: #selector(tapButton(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
button.tintColor = UIColor.white
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "ImageName"), for: UIControlState.normal)
button.setTitle("MyTitle", for: UIControlState.normal)
button.isEnabled = true

func tapButton(sender: UIButton) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Swift 3 version should be:

```
let myButton:UIButton = {
    let myButton = UIButton() // If you want to set the type use like
                              // UIButton(type: .RoundedRect) or
                              // UIButton(type: .Custom)
    myButton.setTitle("Hai Touch Me", for: .normal)
    myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
    myButton.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 40)

    myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.pressedAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(myButton)

    return myButton
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 5** and **Xcode 10.2**

Basically we have **two types** of buttons.

**1) System type button**

**2) Custom type button** (In custom type button we can set background image for button)

And these two types of buttons has few **control states** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/state

Important states are

**1) Normal state**

**2) Selected state**

**3) Highlighted state**

**4) Disabled state** etc...

```
//For system type button
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 250, width: 100, height: 50)
//  button.backgroundColor = .blue
button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13.0)
button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center//Text alighment center
button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0//To display multiple lines in UIButton
button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping//By word wrapping
button.tag = 1//To assign tag value
button.btnProperties()//Call UIButton properties from extension function
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button)

//For custom type button (add image to your button)
let button2 = UIButton(type: .custom)
button2.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 400, width: 100, height: 50)
//        button2.backgroundColor = .blue
button2.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "img.png"), for: .normal)
button2.tag = 2
button2.btnProperties()//Call UIButton properties from extension function
button2.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button2)

@objc func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    print("Button \(sender.tag) clicked")
}

//You can add UIButton properties using extension
extension UIButton {
    func btnProperties() {
        layer.cornerRadius = 10//Set button corner radious
        clipsToBounds = true
        backgroundColor = .blue//Set background colour
        //titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center//add properties like this
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIButton *btnname = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[btnname setTitle:@"Click Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

btnname.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 140);

[self.view addSubview:btnname];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIButton * tmpBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[tmpBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(clearCart:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
tmpBtn.tag = k;
tmpBtn.frame = CGRectMake(45, 0, 15, 15);
[tmpBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CloseButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:tmpBtn];
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

first write this in your .h file of viewcontroller

```
UIButton *btn;
```

Now write this in your .m file of viewcontrollers viewDidLoad.

```
btn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 20, 30, 30)];
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[btn setTitle: @"My Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setTitleColor: [UIColor blueVolor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[btn.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor BlueVolor].CGColor];
//adding action programatically
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

write this outside viewDidLoad method in .m file of your view controller

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
  //Write a code you want to execute on buttons click event
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button setTitle:@"Click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button.frame=CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+10,self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.view.frame.size.width-20, self.view.frame.size.height-500);

 button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20];

[button addTarget:selfaction:@selector(aMethod)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIButton *saveLibrary=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[saveLibrary setTitle:@"Library" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[saveLibrary setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[saveLibrary addTarget:self 
action:@selector(saveOnGalleryButtonIsPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[saveLibrary setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/library225.png"]]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

saveLibrary.frame=CGRectMake(323, 15, 75, 75);  

[self.view addSubview:saveLibrary];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIButton *addProject = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
addProject.frame = CGRectMake(210, 285, 100, 18);
[addProject setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addProject addTarget:self action:@selector(addProjectPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_scrollView addSubview:addProject];
```