# iPhone + add controls dynamically

Tags: iphone, controls, addition

I want to add UILabel controls to my application dynamically from code (programmatically), please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it the following way in one of the view controller methods:

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)]; // Create UILabel
myLabel.tag = someTag; // set label's tag to access this label in future via [view viewWithTag:someTag];
... // set label's properties like text, background and text color, font size etc (e.g. myLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];)
[view addSubView:myLabel]; // add label to your view
[myLabel release]; // view owns the label now so we can release it
```

Comment: is it possible for all kind of controls? (adding complete functionality of controls) i am trying to achive dynamically loading of controls based on XML fetched from server.

Comment: @Ante, sure you can set all properties for any control programmatically

Comment: can you give me code example of dynamically created button that onclick event changes some dynamically created text label?

Comment: @Ante, better create separate question for that. Or search SO - there's a number of similar questions already (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378765/how-do-i-create-a-basic-uibutton-programmatically)