# XCode: Add multiple buttons programmatically with specific names and animate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, programmatically-created

I just read this post about [adding buttons with a loop programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646297/add-a-multiple-buttons-to-a-view-programatically-call-the-same-method-determin).

I want to do the same thing, but do it with a name for each one, and animate them the same way.  Is this a good idea, or should I just copy the same line of code for each button?

Further, I'd like to add a number of buttons (say four) from a list of names (greater than four) and pick them randomly. The catch is, I need them to be named properly and pull images associated with each name. Any ideas?

Thanks SO community!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see it, you should make a property list (.plist) with the array of buttons info - for each button there will be text to display, pic to display and action (method name or something).
You can generate four different random numbers in range `[0, [buttonArray length]]` and then generate your buttons in the loop for each selected number.

I guess, you need something like buttonFactory with method

```
-(UIButton*) makeButtonWithInfo(NSDictionary*)info
```

where name,  picture adress, action etc. stored in info (you custom type buttonInfo if it is complicated).

**Update:**

Create new .plist in Xcode (resources/PropertyList) and fill it like this:
[image]

Read it in your code with

`NSArray* buttonsArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:myPlist.plist];`

There will be dictionaries with button info in this array.

Read in Xcode help about NSArray, NSDictionary and UIButton classes and implement your logic.

Comment: And don't forget to reseed the randomness generator (`srandom(time(NULL));`), or you'll get the same sequence each time. Also, you could use an NSDictionary to hold the string names and pics or pic paths.

Comment: This makes a little sense. I'm new to objective-c. Could you give a little more detail?