# Loop, generating buttons with functions from an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, nsarray, programmatically-created

For my iOS app I have an array of text, and I want to generate inside of my UIScrollview a list of text on the right hand side and a list of buttons on the left hand side. 
Whenever a user presses a UIButton from the right hand side the text from the left hand side will be copied to the user's device's clipboard...

I figured out how to generate the list of text in UILabels using a for loop and an NSArray. I have no clue how to programmatically generate UIButtons though and I also don't know how to make each button copy the respective string from the array (i.e. button #3 copies string #3 (objectAtIndex #2) from the array)

Here is my code so far:

```
    NSArray *copyText;
    copyText = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"text to copy 1", "text to copy 2", "text to copy 3", "text to copy 4", nil];

    int i = 0;
    while (i < [copyText count]) {
        UILabel *copyLabels = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, (ScrollView1.frame.size.width*2/3), 25)];
        copyLabels.center = CGPointMake(ScrollView1.frame.size.width*2/3, ((i*25)+15));
        copyLabels.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        copyLabels.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        copyLabels.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        copyLabels.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:(16.0)];
        [ScrollView1 addSubview:copyLabels];
        copyLabels.text = [NSString stringWithString:[copyLabels objectAtIndex:i]];
        i ++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer here: [Add a multiple buttons to a view programmatically, call the same method, determine which button it was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646297/add-a-multiple-buttons-to-a-view-programatically-call-the-same-method-determin)

The UIButton has a "tag" field in which numeric values can be assigned so my loop can keep track of which button is which. Genius.