# Differentiating between dynamically generated buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch

I have ten options on a view controller, each of which 'pushes' to the same new view controller displaying a specific amount of buttons (**for each option a different amount of buttons may be available, ranging from 3 buttons through to 15**). Currently, my code is performing similarily to the answer posted on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646297/add-a-multiple-buttons-to-a-view-programatically-call-the-same-method-determin).

All these buttons are created dynamically (the amount obviously depending on the length of the array) for each option using a for-loop:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if(option 1) {
    Array contains different values...
    }

    if(option 2) {
    Array contains different values...
    }

    etc...

    for(int i = 0; i < xCoordinatePosition.count; i++) {
       UIButton *imageOne = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
       [imageOne setTag:i];
       [imageOne addTarget:self action:@selector(webViewChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}
```

As you can see I've set a tag for each button to differentiate between the dynamically created buttons, as I want each one to display a different `UIWebView` when selected.

When I've selected an option and NSLog the resulting tags of each button on a results page, I get the reply I'm after: 1, 2, 3 etc.

```
- (IBAction)webViewChanged:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%d", sender.tag);
}
```

The problem is, **I want a unique number for each button in regard to ALL option buttons** - currently each of my ten options returns with buttons that have the tags 1, 2, 3 etc. up to ten, whereas I need the first option return with 1-10, the second option return with 11-20 etc, as each individual button will be returning something unique.

### For example:

**Clicking the button with the tag of 7 on one option will bring up a completely different web-view to clicking on a button with the tag of 7 on another, therefore I need to make a distinction between every button.**

Does anyone know how I could set the tag so that is unique for each option (instead of just setting each button of the currently chosen option to be unique like it does currently)?

Comment: I'm not sure anybody has understood your question. If you want a unique value, then increment it on a static var + modulo. But i can only make wrong statement since i have not understood clearly what you want. You can use an enum too for differenciating the different kind of mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use another integerVariable which have the values multiple of 10.

```
int factor;
if(option 1)
{
   factor = 0;
}
if(option 2)
{
   factor = 10;
} 
etc..
```

Then put tag as,

```
[imageOne setTag:i+factor];
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, one way to solve the problem can be to set a base tag for each option like 100, 200, ...

So, in your `prepareForSegue`:

```
int baseTag;

if(option 1) {
  // Array contains different values...
  baseTag = 100;
}

if(option 2) {
  // Array contains different values...
  baseTag = 200;
}

// etc...
```

And in the for loop, simply:

```
[imageOne setTag: baseTag + i];
```

For option 1, your image tags will start from 101, and for option 2, from 201, etc.