# Detecting which button pressed

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, action, programmatically-created

I want to be able to detect which button is pressed. I wonder if there is some UIButton class method which can will be called automatically when a button is pressed, which allows me to find out the text or tag of the button pressed and pass that on to a variable? Or some objective-c event method that does the same?

I know this topic has been posted here before. The common response appears to be that this would be the solution:

In .h file

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender;
```

In .m file

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender{
// Do something her to display which button pressed
}
```

I have also seen other examples with names such as buttonPressed, onButtonTao etc.

So I assume that this method must be called from each button. However, this does not work, xcode complains when I try to assign the same method to more than one button.

The following example, posted here at Stack, uses the same action, but programatically:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
  UIButton* aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [aButton setTag:i];
  [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [aView addSubview:aButton];
}

// then ...

- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
  NSLog(@"Button %ld clicked.", (long int)[button tag]);
}
```

So, what am I missing here, why does xcode not accept the same method for multiple buttons? And is there some other way to detect which button is pressed without connecting a specific action to each and every button?

Comment: In what way does Xcode complain?

Comment: Connecting multiple controls to the same action method is most definitely possible. You need to be more specific about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect more than one button to the same action method in Xcode.
After creating and connecting the first action, control-drag the remaining buttons
to *the existing action* in the .h file:

[image]

Then you can assign different tags to the buttons in the Attributes Inspector,
 and check `[sender tag]` in the action method.

If you create a new action with the same name, Xcode 
creates another method with the same name, which will cause compiler errors
due to "duplicate declarations".

Comment: I knew it was so simple that when I got the answer, I would feel "of course" :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to Copy-Paste this [Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2646357/1603072) into your Code and it's not working, right ? You should provide **Frame** to the Buttons.

Here is the **Working Code :**

```
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) 
{
    UIButton* aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    aButton.frame = CGRectMake(10 + i*50,10,50,50);
    [aButton setTag:i];
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:aButton];
}
```

Here, frame should not be static otherwise the Buttons will be overlapped.