# Create multiple UIImageViews programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, programmatically-created

I want to create multiple UIImageViews programmatically with different tags and add them as subview of my main view.

I have a property of my UIImageView in header:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *grassImage;
```

then i'm trying to create multiple views:

```
for (int i=0;i<13;i++){

        grassImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

        int randNum = arc4random() % 320; //create random number for x position.

        [grassImage setFrame:CGRectMake(randNum, 200.0, 50.0, 25.0)];
        [grassImage setTag:i+100];
        [grassImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grass"]];

        [self.view addSubview:grassImage];
    }
```

But when I'm trying to access this image views using tag, I'm getting only last tag - 112.

My question - how I can access this views correctly, using their tag?

Similar questions:

- [Add a multiple buttons to a view programmatically, call the same method, determine which button it was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646297/add-a-multiple-buttons-to-a-view-programatically-call-the-same-method-determin)

Comment: You don't need the property declaration at all to use this.

Comment: How do you _"access this image views using tag"_?

Comment: just get using this. UIImageView *imgViewRef = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:TAG_NUMBER];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only getting the last one because you are recreating the same view all the time.

Get rid of that variable, and add your views like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<13;i++){
    UIImageView *grassImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    int randNum = arc4random() % 320; //create random number for x position.

    [grassImage setFrame:CGRectMake(randNum, 200.0, 50.0, 25.0)];
    [grassImage setTag:i+100];
    [grassImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"grass"]];

    [self.view addSubview:grassImage];
}
```

And to get the views:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [self.view viewWithTag:110];
```

Comment: you are creating multiple image views! The answer is not correct. Buy you can only access the last imageview in grassImage. You should still be able to call [self.view viewWithTag:100]; -  [self.view viewWithTag:112]; and access every single one!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for getting subview with a particular `tag`,

```
UIImageView *imgViewRef = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:TAG_NUMBER];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are re-creating the same image again and again, if you access `grassImage` it will give you the last imageview you created. Instead you can get the imageview like this.

```
 for (UIImageView *imgView in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([imgView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            NSLog(@"imageview with tag %d found", imgView.tag);
        }
    }
```