# How to shuffle button or title over button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit

I have 'n' button. I want to shuffle those button in my application. Or you can say that i want to shuffle the title over buttons. Is it possible.Its an Iphone app.

Comment: Of course it's possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [i am using 5 buttons in the cocoa interface builder and i want to shuffle it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404218/i-am-using-5-buttons-in-the-cocoa-interface-builder-and-i-want-to-shuffle-it)

Please don't litter StackOverflow with repeats of your own questions.

Comment: Duplicate yes, but the first question was closed as 'not a question', so it's not like he had a choice.

Comment: You'll notice my name isn't in the list of closers and that I actually attempted to answer his question based on the information he provided (and a little bit of guessing). Not to mention "I opened a new question because my other was voted closed by the community" isn't really a justification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might need to know:

- How to change the position of a button. You can do this with [`frame`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame) property. If you change just the `origin` member of `CGRect`, you can move the button without resizing it.
- How to change the title of a button (if you don't want to change its position). This can be achieved with the [`setTitle:forState:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle:forState:) method of `UIButton`.
- Determining a random number. For general-purpose random number generation, you can use the [`rand()`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/rand.3.html) method. For more serious random number generation there are other methods available but `rand()` should suffice for your needs. Just ensure to call `srand()` with some seed before your first call to `rand()`.
- If you have 100 buttons, you probably should not use Interface Builder but you should create the buttons separately, otherwise you will end up with a class with 100 `IBOutlet` variables. Creating them yourself and maintaining them in an array will give you greater control over their shuffling. Creating them manually has [been discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378765/how-do-i-create-a-basic-uibutton-programmatically) on StackOverflow previously.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible. You can swap titles on two buttons like this:

```
UIButton *b1, *b2;
NSString *tmp;
tmp = [b1 text];
[b1 setText:[b2 text]];
[b2 setText:tmp];
```

You can extend this procedure to n buttons.

Comment: yah it is possible to swap the text.But suppose i have 100 buttons then it won't help. So, What you can do if this is the scenario in front of you? So, find that there is any shuffle methods are available, which can be used to shuffle whole button!!

Comment: Just loop through all of the buttons then and swap at random

Comment: Who would want to use an application with 100 shuffling buttons?!

Comment: this piece of code is not working correctly. I am using third button, on click this button the text over two button swap. Can you have more elaborate  on this topic. thnks

Comment: It's because UIButton no longer has a `setText` method. You have to do `setTitle:forState`.