# How to trigger a button through code, in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, action, programmatically-created

In an iPhone app I am working on, I need to place buttons in a UIScrollView, but because of the fact that I need to place so many buttons to scroll through, I cannot place them in interface builder. Therefore I am having to put them all in the Scroll View through my code. How can I create a button in code, and then use it to trigger an action.

Comment: It's important to distinguish "in Xcode" from "using the API". Xcode is the IDE - the program that helps you organize, compile, build, and package programs you write; Cocoa is the API - the toolkit of ready-made objects and system interfaces you use to write applications for the Mac OS and iOS platforms; Objective-C is the primary language in which the Cocoa frameworks and applications based upon them are written.

Answer (score 3):

See "[How do I create a basic UIButton programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378765/how-do-i-create-a-basic-uibutton-programmatically)". See also the [Target / Action mechanism](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
  UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  //position button
  myButton.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50); 
  [myButton setTitle:@"Click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  // add targets and actions
  [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   // add to a view
   [self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

Further information here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html