# How to create a UIButton from code instead of Interface builder?

Tags: iphone

I tried to write lines below to create a button instead of using Interface Builder. But I couldn't get my button appeared. Is there something wrong with the code? Or there is other steps should be taken.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"button" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
playButton = button;
```

playButton is the IBoutlet of my ViewController.

Comment: Just remember to use `-addSubview`, i.e.: `[self.view addSubview:button];`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a basic UIButton programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378765/how-do-i-create-a-basic-uibutton-programmatically)

Comment: hi Simon: I add these things into the viewDidLoad method: [super viewDidLoad];
 UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
 btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
 [btn setTitle:@"Hello, world!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [self.view addSubview:btn];   But there is still the same problem. Do you know the reason?

Answer (score 2):

You can create it in below way:

UIButton *btnBack=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 450, 52, 27)];

```
[btnBack setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btnBack setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];

[btnBack.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:13.0]];

[btnBack setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-bg-blue-small.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[btnBack setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.view addSubview:btnBack];
```

Let me know in case of any difficulty.

Comment: Hi Nishant. This one is still doesn't work for me :-( I just put your code into viewDidLoad, and add the view of my-ViewController as the subView of main window. After the launching, i was given a big white screen which disappeared after a while. I couldn't figure out the reason really.

Comment: Do one thing. Take one View Based project. Then in "viewDidLoad" method add the above code and check. button will be displayed. Remove unnecessary lines like "setBackgroundImage", "addTarget", etc... Let me know it works.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set the frame  `[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];`