# XCode/Objective-C, load buttons (and other UI elements) at runtime

Tags: objective-c, xcode, runtime

Is it possibile to load buttons at runtime without using .xib files and connect the buttons to class properties anyway (without drag&drop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the "load without .xib" statement do you mean "instantiate in the code", right? in such case the answer is "yes, of course":

```
// interface
@property (retain) UIButton *myButtonProperty;

// implementation

UIButton *tmpButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:...];
...
self.myButtonProperty = tmpButton;
```

Comment: Is it common practice or everybody is using .xibs?

Comment: it is common practice, don't worry; xibs are easy to use and you can prepare a view in short time; I use it 80% of the time. But sometimes, especially for views that can dynamically change, using pure code is easier. Probably writing a code completely without XIBs is not a good idea: you can do it, but you will finish to spend a lot of time in resizing the views and setting properties, while with IB this is immediate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You can create button object and add it to a view. More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378765/how-do-i-create-a-basic-uibutton-programmatically).