# Subclass UIView from ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, viewcontroller

I'm trying to show an onscreen tutorial (like a picture with hints) in my viewController. I only know how to "open" a `UIView` with its `drawRect` method, where my paint code is inside, from the AppDelegate with:

```
BannerView *view = [[BannerView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.frame];
[self.window addSubview:view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Is it possible to activate the `UIView` (BannerView) by a button from inside a ViewController?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this code:

```
BannerView *view = [[BannerView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

in your button action method (if it is defined in your controller class). See this S.O. question to know [how to create a button programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378765/how-do-i-create-a-basic-uibutton-programmatically). Otherwise, you can use interface builder for that.

Using `self.view.bounds` in `initWithFrame` will make your banner view as large as the controller's view (which could be smaller than the display).

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is adding an event handler to a button on the view controller that will create the view and add the view by using something like

```
BannerView *view = [[BannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

where self is the view controller.