# I cannot make a UIButton programatically

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have searched all of the internet, it seems that every post on this topic leaves out one vital piece of info that i need. no matter what people tell me to do, i cannot get rid of a "undeclared identifier" error with everything/anything regarding my method for my button's action. I have picked at the code so much that it is totally jacked up. Can anyone tell me what exactly i need to to do make a proper interactive button? Everything that goes in the .m file and .h file for viewcontroller? 
please don't assume that I already have a certain vital piece of code, because I might not. I am new to objective-c. 
Thank you!!!!!!!! ( it is for ipad by the way, and i am avoiding using the storyboard )thanks!! i am very frustrated at this point.

here is my code so far

```
    UIButton *add = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[add addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[add setTitle:@"add new" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
add.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
[objects addSubview:add];
- (void)aMethod:(UIButton*)button
{
    NSLog(@"Button  clicked.");
}
```

And the problem isn't that it runs and then crashes, the problem is that i can't run it to begin with as long as I have this error "Use of undeclared identifier 'aMethod'"

Comment: Please post whatever code you have so that we can have a look.

Comment: If you're very new in iOS, I suggest you to start with Paul Hegarty lections. https://itunes.apple.com/ru/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255?mt=10

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a basic UIButton programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378765/how-do-i-create-a-basic-uibutton-programmatically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 .what is object in this line     [object addSubview:add];
    try this

    UIButton *add = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [add addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [add setTitle:@"add new" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    add.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
     [object addSubview:add];


    - (void)aMethod
    {
        NSLog(@"Button  clicked.");
    }
```

Comment: object is the name of a scrollview i am trying to add it to. I will try that code

Comment: again, i am getting the "undeclared identifier" error for "aMethod"

Comment: - (void)aMethod; pest this line in .h file and then .m file use this - (void)aMethod
{
    NSLog(@"Button  clicked.");
}

Comment: (aMethod) remove :  change this line

Comment: thanks for helping me, i am still getting the same error though. and to make sure were still on the same page this what i have in .h `- (void)aMethod;` no errors there... and here is what i have in .m `    UIButton *add = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [add addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [add setTitle:@"add new" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    add.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
    [self.view addSubview:add];
    
    
- (void)aMethod { NSLog(@"Button clicked."); }`

Comment: (aMethod) : remove this

Comment: if it makes any difference, I am also getting the same " undeclared identifier" as a warning instead of error on the "addtarget" line

Comment: remove it from the "add target" line? or the "void" line?

Comment: - (void)aMethod
    {
        NSLog(@"Button  clicked.");
    } have you used this it is working for me why not for you

Comment: that's what I have, it's not working. Could there be some other factor involved? could it be an issue of global/non global variables?

Comment: and also I just noticed that at the top of my .m file i have a warning for my `@implementation ViewController` line that sais "Method definition of aMethod not found"

Comment: but you have - (void)aMethod { NSLog(@"Button clicked."); } this in .m

Comment: hmm.. i dont know. I will look through and make sure nothing is being excluded on a global level. thanks for all the help. I will consider this answered because I now know a little more than i did before

Answer (score 5):

Please try this code

```
  UIButton *submitButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 300, 70, 50)];
[submitButton.layer setCornerRadius:10.0]; 
[submitButton setTitle:@"Submit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[submitButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitAction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:submitButton];
```

Comment: thanks, and from there, where and how to I add my custom piece of code that runs as a result of pressing the button?

Comment: Plz add this viewDidLoad

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: thank you! now where/how to I add my custom piece of code that runs after pressing the button. I have gotten this far before, it is when i try to make the button do something, that is when everything crumbles.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

Once you press the button it will look for buttonClicked: action event automatically

```
-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton *)clicked{ //Your action goes here...}
```

Comment: but now I am getting "undeclared identifier 'buttonClicked'"