# UIButton not working in iphone5s while working while using adhoc build

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have created a button

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *sendBtn;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton * send;
```

//here is the code for button

```
CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(270, 0, 60, 45); 
send = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonFrame];
[send setTitle: @"send" forState: UIControlStateNormal]; 
[send addTarget:self action:@selector(sendMsgAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[send setTitleColor: [UIColor redColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal]; 
[self addSubview:send];
self.otherBtn = send; self.sendBtn = send;
```

When i run it using developer profile it works correct
But while using adhoc build it don't respond.

**NOTE: it works fine in iphone4s,ipad2,iphone5 with adhoc and developer both but not working in iphone5s using adhoc build,while using developer work fine**

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378765/how-do-i-create-a-basic-uibutton-programmatically

Comment: no button is correct,it might be some architecture issue of IOS version issue or might be developer or adhoc build issue causes such...is anyone face such striange behaviour??

Comment: NOTE: down voters please comment reason to down vote!

Comment: instead of `send = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonFrame];` just say `send.frame = buttonFrame`. It will work

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1** : Never use reserve keywords. `SEND` should be sendButton or something else.

**Point 2** : As I see you have `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton * send;` means you are connecting the button with IB.

As you already have button in IB, don't define it again in code. So I would say, instead of

```
send = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonFrame];
```

use it as

```
send.frame = buttonFrame;
```

Hope this will solve your problem...