# How to create a UIButton programmatically in iOS 14 in objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiaction

I'm trying to create a UIButton programmatically in iOS 14 (beta 3) in objective-C.  This is what I've tried, but the UIAction handler is never called when I tap the button:

```
UIAction *tapAction = [UIAction actionWithHandler:^(UIAction* action){
     NSLog(@"Never gets here");
}];
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) primaryAction:tapAction];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate [How do I create a basic UIButton programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378765/how-do-i-create-a-basic-uibutton-programmatically)

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  My old code using addTarget doesn't work on iOS 14.  The target is never called.  My understanding is that iOS 14 changes the way the target is specified by requiring a UIAction.

Comment: To clarify, I am using Xcode 12 beta 3.

Comment: macOS Big Sur 11.0 beta, Xcode 12.0 beta 4, iOS 14.0 beta 3 - based on the code from the linked duplicate - works fine for me - your problem is somewhere else

Comment: Yes, I figured out that the issue is caused by the fact that the button was inside a table view cell.  Prior to iOS 14, the target is called, but on iOS 14, it is not.  As a workaround, I use didSelectRowAtIndexPath and find the button in the cell and call the target directly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It looks like a bug to me. Try adding:

```
 self.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

to *init(style:reuseIdentifier:)* if you are using a custom tableview cell. Please refer to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661508?page=1#636261022 and @OOPer great answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I normally create a button in Objective-C:

```
- (void)createButton {
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 100);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
    
- (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
   // Do your logic here
}
```

You can read more here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget

Comment: This is what my old code does, but on iOS 14 it fails to reach the selector.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a test app that just displays a button and it's working, so the issue must be something else in my main app.  Thanks all.