# presentCodeRedemptionSheet() is not working

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription, in-app

I am creating offer codes with auto-renewable In-app purchases in swift. But when i use presentCodeRedemptionSheet(), it does not show any redemption page to redeem offer code. I am using below code, but nothing is happening on tapping the button.

```swift
let paymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        paymentQueue.presentCodeRedemptionSheet()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running it on the device with iOS 14?

Comment: yes running iOS 14.0.1

Comment: I tried your code, and it worked instantly. You wrote something about a button you tap. Could it be that this button isn't connected correctly with the action?

Comment: @PaulSchröder can you please provide any tutorial link, might be I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @Man_Parashar see here for basically all possibilities on how to create a button: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1378765/1128713

Comment: thanks, @PaulSchröder, its working now, but it was not working with sandbox when I tried it with my live apple account, it started displaying the redemption sheet.

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying on the simulator?

This command only works on a **real device** not in the simulator.

Comment: no, on a real device. Actually, I was trying to test it with the Sandbox acc but it was not working, i have checked the docs and found that it will only works with production apple acc.

Comment: But how can we be sure that this only works in production? Is there any way to test it before we make it live?

Comment: You can see the view presented even with Sandbox, but than when you input code it returns "incorrect code" if you are on sandbox version