# presentCodeRedemptionSheet,how works on sanbox

Tags: ios

I've implemented presentCodeRedemptionSheet() in an app to accept codes and generated some in App Store Connect, but if I run the app locally in debug and try to enter a code it asks me to download the App Store version of the app.

How Can I Do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [presentCodeRedemptionSheet() is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68193747/presentcoderedemptionsheet-is-not-working)

Comment: Hi @well_King ,i have same problem, have you find any way to test offer code?